# T-SQL Case Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to write a function for our **SQL Server 2000** that I can use in other stored procedures to clean up our machine ID numbers:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Description: The Purpose here is to just get the System (Chamber, Decay, Label, Tubing, etc.)
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetSysType] (@systemID varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(50) AS
BEGIN
  declare @sysID varchar(50)
  set @sysID=LTrim(RTrim(@systemID))
  if (0<Len(@sysID)) begin
    set @sysID=(
      case when (0<CharIndex('Inspect', @sysID)) then 'Inspect'
*     case when (0<CharIndex('Label', @sysID)) then 'Label'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Tubing', @sysID)) then 'Tubing'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Expand', @sysID)) then 'Expand'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Decay', @sysID)) then 'Decay'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Chamber', @sysID)) then 'Chamber'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Water', @sysID)) then 'Water'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Sniff', @sysID)) then 'Sniff'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Packout', @sysID)) then 'Packout'
      case when (0<CharIndex('Shipping', @sysID)) then 'Shipping'
      else 'Unknown' end)
  end
  return @sysID
END
GO
```

The error message when I try to save this is:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.*

at the asterisk above.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258235(v=sql.80).aspx) for the CASE statement?

Comment: Oh, I did. Obviously, I just can't read very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `CASE` once.

```
...
set @sysID=(
  case when (0<CharIndex('Inspect', @sysID)) then 'Inspect'
       when (0<CharIndex('Label', @sysID)) then 'Label'
       when (0<CharIndex('Tubing', @sysID)) then 'Tubing'
       when (0<CharIndex('Expand', @sysID)) then 'Expand'
       when (0<CharIndex('Decay', @sysID)) then 'Decay'
       when (0<CharIndex('Chamber', @sysID)) then 'Chamber'
       when (0<CharIndex('Water', @sysID)) then 'Water'
       when (0<CharIndex('Sniff', @sysID)) then 'Sniff'
       when (0<CharIndex('Packout', @sysID)) then 'Packout'
       when (0<CharIndex('Shipping', @sysID)) then 'Shipping'
  else 'Unknown' end)
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, how to award...?

Comment: If you're asking whom to award it to; if the answers are the same, then you award to the earliest answer.

Comment: Yeah, but yours was here first, but then it got edited so much that it now says it was answered after the 2nd answer.

Comment: Aha. You should be able to check the revision history if you wanted to.

Comment: @jp2code where does it say this one is answered after the 2nd answer? Hold your mouse over the "answered 10 mins ago" or whatever it says, and it will show the timestamp to the second in a tooltip. Also if you switch the tab above to "oldest" it will order oldest first.

Comment: Also you can't see revision history for "grace period" edits. You can make as many changes as you want to an answer within the first 5 minutes - after the 5 minutes has expired, all of your revisions are gone (at least to regular users).

Comment: Man. You SQL guys are a tough crowd. I'm already at a (-3) on this. I'll have to remember to post my SQL Noobie questions someplace else.

Comment: If it helps, I gave your question a +1.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server syntax for case is:

```
set @sysID=(
      case when (0<CharIndex('Inspect', @sysID)) then 'Inspect'
           when (0<CharIndex('Label', @sysID)) then 'Label'
           when (0<CharIndex('Tubing', @sysID)) then 'Tubing'
           when (0<CharIndex('Expand', @sysID)) then 'Expand'
           when (0<CharIndex('Decay', @sysID)) then 'Decay'
           when (0<CharIndex('Chamber', @sysID)) then 'Chamber'
           when (0<CharIndex('Water', @sysID)) then 'Water'
           when (0<CharIndex('Sniff', @sysID)) then 'Sniff'
           when (0<CharIndex('Packout', @sysID)) then 'Packout'
           when (0<CharIndex('Shipping', @sysID)) then 'Shipping'
      else 'Unknown' end)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Aw man! That's even the MSDN page I was looking at to write the code!